# Reading strings from txt files into NSArrays in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

After much reading it seems that, really, the only way to read a  number of lines from a text file into an `NSArray` is with this:

```
NSString *myfilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"poem" ofType:@"txt"];

NSString *linesFromFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myfilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

myArrayOfLines = [NSArray alloc];
myArrayOfLines = [linesFromFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

`NSArrays` have a method for `initWithContentsOfFile` but I have not seen any examples of how to use this.  I have read some posts that state that the file must be a plist and not a generic txt file.

Is this really the case?  Is there a way to read lines (terminated with `\n`) directly into an `NSArray`?

Comment: Not really related to the question, but you do not need this line: myArrayOfLines = [NSArray alloc]; (which is missing the init call anyway), as you are assigning myArrayOfLines on the line after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it right, except the line `myArrayOfLines = [NSArray alloc];` which is useless.
Don't bother with plist if you already have a good txt file. 
But for curiosity, here is a link which explains how it works with plist files : [link](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/reading-a-plist-into-an-nsarray.html)

Also, if you don't use ARC, you'll have some leaks, but that's another question, and we don't have the whole code, so I might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I tried to bundle the allocation and init into the one line as I usually do but it did  not seem to "fit".  I'll dump it.  Thanks for the link - I read that one in my travels and as a result nearly went to plists but I have a reason for wanting txt files.  The process I have is not that painful but I really wanted initWithContentsOfFile to work "off the bat".  Cheers.

Comment: @"\n" did not worked for me, had to use @"\r", as stated in Apple documentation.